# Caesar encrypt / decrypt objects

Tags: java, object-oriented, caesar-cipher

I have created some object-oriented program for Caesar encryption. Could you please check if I have done anything wrong or how I can improve this? This is for my school assignment on coding and I would like to impress my teacher as a Java beginner. Thanks.

I would like my code to be well written and suitable for performing Caesar encryption and decryption.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarEncryptOOP {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // class variables
    // -------------------------------------------------

    private  String SzText;
    private int iShift;
    protected static String SzEncryptMessage;


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public CaesarEncryptOOP()
    {
        reset();
        return;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Setters
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setText(String message) 
    {
        SzText = message;
    }

    public void setShift(int Shift) 
    {
        //Shift higher than the value 30 or below 0 will be set to 0
        if(Shift <= 30 && Shift >= 0) {
        iShift = Shift;
        }
        else
        {
        iShift = 0;
        }
    }

    public void setOutpt(String OUTPT) 
    {
        SzEncryptMessage = OUTPT;
    }

    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public int getShift()
    {
        return iShift;
    }
    
    public String getText()
    {
        return SzText;
    }
    
    public String getOutpt()
    {
        return SzEncryptMessage;
    }

    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Utilities
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public void reset() {
        setText ("abcxyz");
        setOutpt("");
        setShift(16);
    } 
    
    public static void Encrypt () {
        

        CaesarEncryptOOP myCaesarEncryptOOP = new CaesarEncryptOOP();
        myCaesarEncryptOOP.setShift(2);
        myCaesarEncryptOOP.setText("abcdefg");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myCaesarEncryptOOP.getText().length(); i++)
        {
            // Shifts through the input text i is the position of the character
            char cAlphabet = myCaesarEncryptOOP.getText().charAt(i);

            // if input text lies between a and z
            if (cAlphabet >= 'a' && cAlphabet <= 'z' )
            {
                // shift alphabet
                cAlphabet = (char)(cAlphabet + myCaesarEncryptOOP.getShift());

                //if input is larger than Z continue shift from A 
                if(cAlphabet > 122) {
                    cAlphabet = (char)(cAlphabet- 26); 
                }

                SzEncryptMessage = myCaesarEncryptOOP.getOutpt() + cAlphabet;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        //Output Encrypted data
        System.out.println("Encoded message : " + myCaesarEncryptOOP.SzEncryptMessage);
    }
    

    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // main
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        System.out.println("Welcome to my caesar Encrypter!");
        System.out.println("The shift must be 30 or smaller");
        Encrypt();
    

    }
```

```
public class CaesarDecryptOOP extends CaesarEncryptOOP {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public CaesarDecryptOOP()
    {
        Decrypt();
        reset();
        return;

    }
    public static void Decrypt () {

        CaesarEncryptOOP myCaesardecryptOOP = new CaesarEncryptOOP();
        myCaesardecryptOOP.setShift(2);
        myCaesardecryptOOP.setText("cdefghi");

        for (int i = 0; i < myCaesardecryptOOP.getText().length(); i++)
        {
            // Shifts through the input text i is the position of the character
            char cAlphabet = myCaesardecryptOOP.getText().charAt(i);

            // if input text lies between a and z
            if (cAlphabet >= 'a' && cAlphabet <= 'z' )
            {
                // shift alphabet
                cAlphabet = (char)(cAlphabet - myCaesardecryptOOP.getShift());

                //if input is larger than Z continue shift from A 
                if(cAlphabet < 97) {
                    cAlphabet = (char)(cAlphabet + 26); 
                }

                SzEncryptMessage = myCaesardecryptOOP.getOutpt() + cAlphabet;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        //Output Encrypted data
        System.out.println("Encoded message : " + myCaesardecryptOOP.SzEncryptMessage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my caesar Decrypter!");
        Decrypt();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a Java beginner, you're doing OK - but even in a program as simple as this there's a lot to learn.

I find the "OOP" suffix on your class name to be redundant - pretty much everything in idiomatic Java is OOP.

Your `sz`, etc. prefixes are [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) which has generally fallen out of favour. It makes life more difficult instead of easier - it doesn't help in legibility; and thankfully Java has good types already so the type of a variable will never be unclear. Just drop these prefixes.

You've captured the wrong state. Thinking about modelling a "useful object": a useful object could be an encryptor, which knows everything that it needs to know about how to encrypt and decrypt text but doesn't store the text itself. In this case the only thing it needs is the shift value, and since you can make that value immutable you should use a record instead of a class. Along this line: `reset()` is a code smell; it fights against the idea of immutable instances. One encryptor instance holding a constant shift value can be reused for any number of messages with no reset needed.

Your `return;` is redundant.

You have a whole rainbow of random variable cases - TitleCase, lowerCamelCase and even UPPERCASE. For Java, lowerCamelCase is standard.

You need to do away with the idea of getters and setters for their own sake. You don't need any of them in this application.

Your program would be much more useful if it accepted a shift and a message in the terminal instead of using baked-in constants.

Consider using Java streams instead of a loop over your string characters.

Don't write numeric constants like 122 (or even 26) when you can use `'z'` character literals.

Don't print in your processing routines - only print on the outer level, where your terminal interaction takes place.

`Encrypt` (which should be named `encrypt`) should be an instance method and not a `static`.

`The shift must be 30 or smaller` is, first of all, untrue: with the right modular arithmetic you can accept shifts of basically any value. Also, it's not very useful to state this without then enforcing it during input validation.

Note that this is a [symmetric-key algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) which means that it's not worth defining separate encryption and decryption programs. It's enough to tell the user to input a positive shift for encryption and a negative shift for decryption.

Make better use of built-ins like `Character.isAlphabetic(symbol)` rather than attempting this yourself.

### Suggested

```
package com.stackexchange.caesarexample;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public record CaesarEncrypt(int shift) {
    private static final int range = 'z' - 'a' + 1;

    private String applyShift(int symbol) {
        // if input text lies between a and z
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(symbol)) {
            int offset = Character.toLowerCase(symbol) - 'a';

            // shift alphabet
            // if input is larger than Z continue shift from A
            // The ugly-looking modular arithmetic is to address an edge case involving negative numbers;
            // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-does-java-do-modulus-calculations-with-negative-numbers
            int newOffset = ((offset + shift) % range + range) % range;

            symbol += newOffset - offset;
        }

        return Character.toString(symbol);
    }

    public String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        return plaintext.chars()
            .mapToObj(this::applyShift)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println("Welcome to my Caesar encryptor!");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        out.print("Enter the shift (positive to encrypt, negative to decrypt): ");
        CaesarEncrypt encryptor = new CaesarEncrypt(in.nextInt());
        in.nextLine();

        out.print("Enter the text to process: ");
        String ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(in.nextLine());

        out.printf("Processed text: %s%n", ciphertext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse the record type like this. :) It is meant to reduce the boiler plate on data objects and a cryptographic cipher is not a DAO.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen Certainly this is not a DAO, but applications of records are not and should not be restricted to DAOs. Simple, immutable objects are one way to drag Java (kicking and screaming) into some semblance of the present. Would you rather all simple, non-DAO objects receive the boilerplate that you describe?

Comment: Since record keyword was intended to be used in DAOs only, whoever reads your code will first assume that they are looking at a data object and be confused when they find a cipher (like I did). Your choice of using records in a context they were not intended for adds to cognitive load for the reader and thus makes your code less maintainable. The purpose of Code Review is not to drag Java anywhere. It's to improve existing code, so let's leave the ideological discussion about how Java should be developed somewhere else.

Comment: In your code you don't split the encryption / decryption into separate parts such as calculating the index / character, there is no parameter checking, the input / output is not in balance (int to string), you name the index an offset, etc. I would have more to say about it if you'd post that as a question here.